# PYQT: mainwindow closes while having second and third window open

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I need some help in my current problem.

I have a window with three buttons. When pressing two of them ("GraphicButton" and "QuestionButton") a second and third window shall open. This works fine. The third button "ImportButton" is for populating a table widget in the mainwindow with a dataframe from excel. 
When I press the "ImportButton" first everything works fine.

BUT when I press one of the other buttons first to open the other windows and THEN press the "ImportButton", the mainwindow and the other ones will close.

I could use some advice here.
Here is my code for `main.py`:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import os
from qtpy import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

from ui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from ui.graphwindow import Ui_GraphWindow
from ui.questionwindow import Ui_QuestionWindow

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.ui.ImportButton.clicked.connect(self.import_clicked)
        self.ui.GraphicButton.clicked.connect(self.graphic_clicked)
        self.ui.QuestionButton.clicked.connect(self.question_clicked)

    def import_clicked(self):
        self.ui.RefWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.ui.LubWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.ui.MixWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)

        self.ui.RefWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.ui.LubWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.ui.MixWidget.setRowCount(0)

        if self.ui.RefBoxC.currentIndex() == 0:
            A = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"./Datenbank/CO2.xlsx")
            df = pd.read_excel(A)

            self.ui.RefWidget.setColumnCount(len(df.columns))
            self.ui.RefWidget.setRowCount(len(df.index))

            for i in range(len(df.index)):
                for j in range(len(df.columns)):
                    self.ui.RefWidget.setItem(i, j, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(df.iat[i, j])))

            self.ui.RefWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
            self.ui.RefWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
        else:
            A = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./Datenbank/PlatzhalterRef.xlsx")
            df = pd.read_excel(A)

            self.ui.RefWidget.setColumnCount(len(df.columns))
            self.ui.RefWidget.setRowCount(len(df.index))

            for i in range(len(df.index)):
                for j in range(len(df.columns)):
                    self.ui.RefWidget.setItem(i, j, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(df.iat[i, j])))

            self.ui.RefWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
            self.ui.RefWidget.resizeRowsToContents()

        self.ui.RefWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.ui.LubWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.ui.MixWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def graphic_clicked(self):
        self.Gwindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_GraphWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.Gwindow)
        self.Gwindow.show()

    def question_clicked(self):
        self.Questwindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_QuestionWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.Questwindow)
        self.Questwindow.show()

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: the solution provided by this answer has not been tested and may be incomplete.*

When you click either the `GraphicButton` or `QuestionButton`,

```
self.ui = Ui_GraphWindow()
```

or

```
self.ui = Ui_QuestionWindow()
```

This will modify `self.ui`. When the `ImportButton` is clicked, `self.ui` will refer to the other windows. This, I believe, is **unintentional**.

When the commands in `import_clicked()` are run, there may be references to undefined classes, widgets, and whatnot.

```
self.ui.RefWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
```

I'm guessing RefWidget is not defined in Ui_QuestionWindow or Ui_GraphWindow.

<s>To solve this, try adding</s>

```
def import_clicked(self):
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()   # set self.ui to refer to a MainWindow
    # ...
```

and see if it works. (**Warning: a new MainWindow may be created and the old MainWindow be left forsaken.** Again, I haven't tested this to see if it *does* create a new MainWindow but my intuition tells me that it does.)

*EDIT: Above suggestion in strikethrough did not work for OP.*

If further trouble and chaos ensues, consider having three separate member variables instead of a single `self.ui`.

```
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super().__init__(parent)

    self.uiMain = Ui_MainWindow()              # new member variable: self.uiMain
    # ...

def import_clicked(self):   

    self.uiMain.RefWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
    self.uiMain.LubWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
    self.uiMain.MixWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
    # ...

def graphic_clicked(self):
    self.Gwindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.uiGraphic = Ui_GraphWindow()          # new member variable: self.uiGraphic
    # ...

def question_clicked(self):
    self.Questwindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.uiQuestion = Ui_QuestionWindow()      # new member variable: self.uiQuestion
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks! First advice did not work. The mainwindow closed no matter when i press the "ImportButton".
Second advice works fine and makes sense. Thanks a lot!